# Python - only allow specific words (variables) and mathematical operators as input

Tags: python, regex, validation

What is the best way in python to validate a string so that it only contains specific (pre-defined) words or some other characters [e.g. +, -, /, *, (, ) ]?

My end goal is to validate input (string which will be used as a mathematical formula), for example:

```
foo = Valid
fooo = Invalid
bar = Valid
foo/(bar+foo) = Valid
foo*bar - foo = Valid
foo + tree = Invalid
+ = Invalid
```

I have been searching for and found similar questions but none that seem to fit exactly my needs.
I have kind of managed to create a flawed workaround where I do the following:

```
allowed_words = ('foo', 'bar', ' + ') # and so on... which is tedious 
input_str = raw_input("foo + bar")
split_string = re.split('(\W+)', input_str)
for word in split_string:
    match = False
    for allowed_word in allowed_words:
        if word == allowed_word:
            match = True
        else:
            pass
    if match == True:
        print "%s is valid" % word
    else:
        print "%s is NOT valid" % word
```

I also attempted to use

`if not re.match = ("(\b(?=foo\b|bar\b|\d+\b)\w+\b)|\s|[*/+()-]", input_str)`

which seemed to work here: http://regexr.com (but I suspect re.match is not the right way to go..)

Could someone please inform me of the best way to achieve my goal? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds very much like you want a very simple domain-specific language rather than a pure regex solution - you need to have some notion of context to do this right, which regular expressions just can't give you. There are good [Python parsing and lexing](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) solutions out there. You want a lexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the canonical lexing and parsing problem: how do you identify a string of characters as valid tokens and interpret whether they are valid?

Regular expressions are involved, but not in the way you think: regular expressions are usually insufficient by themselves when you have a formal grammar to match against (which you do, otherwise simply having a `+` with no operands would be considered valid).

[PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) is a parser-lexer written in Python that is essentially a port of Lex and Yacc. It will take out much of the burden in solving this problem and requires fairly little code to get this done.

Your grammar is pretty much the calculator grammar with a simple modification (the following is in Brackus-Naur format):

> expression : expression + term
>              | expression - term
>              | term
>
> term       : term * factor
>              | term / factor
>              | factor
>
> factor     : IDENTIFIER
>              | ( expression )

where `IDENTIFIER` here can represent any of the valid words you want. You can even go one step further and replace `IDENTIFIER` with the specific words you want it to parse. The PLY page I linked to gives a full tutorial on how to implement this, complete with code.

For the lexer, you need only specify the the individual regexes that match a token. In other words, you only need to tell the lexer to tag all strings that look like a `+` as a `PLUS`, rather than every possible combination of these characters. This saves a lot of trouble: you no longer have just one regular expression matching the whole string, only a regular expression to identify each part of a string. Again, the PLY documentation covers this exhaustively.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything Liongold said. But let's assume for a moment that your requirements are only what you explicitly stated:

> What is the best way in python to validate a string so that it only
>   contains specific (pre-defined) words or some other characters?

then a slight tweak of your regex can satisfy it:

```
^([\s*\/+()-]*(?=foo\b|bar\b|\d+\b)\w+[\s*\/+()-]*)+$
```

(i got rid of the `|\s|[*/+()-]` at the end of your pattern and moved that logic into parentheses, while also accounting for leading operators, then quantified that whole structure:

(*operators/spaces SPECIALWORD operators/spaces*), one or more of these, anchored by `^` and `$` to ensure that the whole line must match.

*aside: you also do not need to "eat" the \b boundaries, since they are zero-width and you are consuming nothing anyway.*

[DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/bA0nQ7/3)